# How to draw straight lines of a given length

Tags: modeling, snapping

I am trying to reproduce the following picture (white outline) in blender, so that I can use the loft command on it.

[image]

Is there any way to do that shape using straight lines and measuring distances and angles?

I have done it pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and inserting a Plane, from which I delete a vertex and with the use of <kbd>E</kbd> I extrude line by line until I get the shape I am looking for, but I would like to know if there is a more reliable and precise way to do it.

Comment: Hi, a simple way, but limited, is to input extrusion units by the keyboard, like: "E > X > 2 > confirm", that will extrude on X axis by 2 blender units

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all your measures are integers and all your angles are 45 degrees, you can use **[Precision control](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/precision/introduction.html#usage)**.

Once you have started an extrusion (<kbd>E</kbd>) the displacement is displayed at the bottom of the 3D Viewport:

[image]
(image from [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/basics.html))

Keeping an eye on it, before accepting the new position, you can **hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>** (while moving the pointer) for "snapping" the transform to an integer number of grid units, or 10 grid units: it depends on your current zoom level. If you need a 10 times finer precision, hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> together.

For 45 degrees displacements, make sure that Dx and Dy are the same value, apart from the sign.

Once you have done, you can measure distances and angles using the *MeasureIt* addon.

Comment: The link is broken